# What's the proper way of implementing 'sleeping' technique using C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Two thread. Main one is constantly gathering notifications while the other one is processing some of them.
The way i implemet it - is not correct as i've been told. What problems is it causing and what's wrong about it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

std::condition_variable foo;
std::mutex mtx;

void secondThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
            foo.wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mtx));
            std::cout << " ----------------------------" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "|processing a notification...|" << std::endl;
            std::cout << " ----------------------------" << std::endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::thread subThread = std::thread(&secondThread);
    int count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (count % 10 == 0)
        {
            foo.notify_one();
        }
        std::cout << "Main thread working on gathering notifications..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was told that this `foo.wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mtx))` line of code is not a good practice according to the C++ spec. This is not a proper way of solving this kind of problem. It's also called, sleeping(not busy waiting).

Comment: It doesn't compile.

Comment: @Galik. It compiles. I tested that before posting.(MSVC, x86)

Comment: hint: `mutex` is supposed to perform thread synchronizing, in your code only one thread uses it.

Comment: It appears your question should be "how do condition variables work and when to use them", and then you can answer this question by yourself.

Comment: You might have spurious wake_up in `wait`.

Comment: It doesn't compile for me and looking at the docs I don't see why it should compile. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Galik The default language extensions for Visual Studio allows binding temporaries to non-const references.

Comment: Ah well that's non standard....

Comment: MSVC emits a warning at /w4 bit it does allow it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb i agree with you but if you could, can you specify some possible design faults this code can create or what's bad about it? I'm on my learing path and i must know should i continue listen to the guy who told me this code is a terrible practice or not.

Comment: Well if it compiled, the obvious problem I see is the scope of the temporary lock. It goes out of scope as soon as you obtain it

Comment: What are the reasons he gave to you ?

Comment: Of at least its working must dependent on how `wait` is implemented.

Comment: The problem is that `condition_variable` is designed to work with a condition  (some variable) which is synchronized by the mutex that's locked with the lock you provide it. Without a condition, spurious wake can cause you problems. In any case, this example isn't representative of when you would use `condition_variable` as it doesn't synchronize any data. You could just use `std::this_thread::sleep_for` directly in the worker and get the desired result. Instead, you provide `count` to the worker, synchronized by `mtx`, and have the worker check the modulo. Then you'd have a condition.

Comment: @Jarod42 like none. He just pointed out that this technique is a terrible practice and it's not allowed by the C++ spec. In other words, you can't program like that in C++. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Standard `C++` should not compile this because... binding to non const reference is not allowed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux in your case, the _sleeping_ would become _busy waiting_, which works a bit differently. Point is, i need to implement the _sleeping_ one. I hope you know the differrence at OS level.

Comment: [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) is not "busy waiting". It sleeps in the sense that the thread blocks rather then spins.

Comment: I would say `std::mutex mtx; std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mtxl(mtx); ` and pass `mtxl` to `.wait`. Since you only need to process some of the notifications and not all, that's enough and no counter or something is needed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux as much as i know, it doesn't really sleep. It still there, occuping the system resourses and to _wake up_ this thread, you don't use wake up instructions because it doesn't sleep.

Comment: Just take care of spurious wakeups.. if that's relevant. Could be solved by an `atomic<bool> x;` that the notification thread sets before waking.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux not sure I get the proposal to call `sleep_for`. For how long should it sleep?

Comment: @Scarlett If anything, I would expect `std::conditional_variable` to consume more system resources (though I can't confirm that). But in both cases, the thread continues to exist and consume resources... The thread doesn't disappear while it waits for the condition. I think there may be a misunderstanding regarding terminology.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The point I was trying to make was that in this example there is no exchange of information between the worker and the main thread. You could just sleep 3 seconds in the worker.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux spurious wakeups should not occur very often according to my sources, so there's still substantial difference.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'm not sure what difference you mean.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux waiting for 3 seconds always waits for at least 3 seconds. But waiting on the condition variable will never sleep longer than till the next notification. Sometimes it may wake up earlier, but it will happen (according to my sources) rarely.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb `std::conditional_variable::wait` may also have a delay. The language doesn't specify how and when blocked threads get scheduled by the operating system. It simply states that a notification can unblock the waiting thread. And discounting spurious wake is not portable. You can't assume the frequency.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux all CPU instructions have a delay. But like a call to `wait`, they are way below 3 seconds by any practical means and therefore my `wait` call will lead to better notification latency. For the portability issue, you can put "Only supported on Linux" in the README.md file.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb In the absence of platform and compiler tags, it's assumed the question is asking for a language conforming answer. Note that using `sleep_for` is *not* a proposed answer. I used it to illustrate that the worker and main threads do not need to communicate. Finally, the delay on wake for `sleep_for` is allowed specifically *"due to scheduling or resource contention delays."*. The same delays inherent to `conditional_variable`' wait.

Comment: It's still conforming with many spurious wakeups, but just behaves less desirable. You always have this problem with unknown platforms that you haven't tested your program with. The prints with `cout` may block the program progress for long periods of time, seconds, even minutes, if the destination device lags. As you say, the scheduler may have undesirable properties aswell wrt time slices for threads. The programm will still be conforming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163351/discussion-between-francois-andrieux-and-johannes-schaub-litb).

Comment: The entire point of moving this to chat is that the comment section is not the place for a discussion. Why are you making a copy of it here?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I agree. Using condition_variable here seems not to be the best way. I guess I find this chat thing confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Before you call `wait`, you must check that the thing you are waiting for hasn't already happened. And before you stop calling `wait`, you must check that the thing you are waiting for *has* happened. Condition variables are stateless and have no idea what you're waiting for. It's your job to code that.

Also, the associated mutex *must* protect the thing you're waiting for. The entire point of a condition variable is to provide an atomic "unlock and wait" operation to prevent this problem:

1. You check if you need to wait under the protection of a mutex.
2. You decide you do need to wait.
3. You unlock the mutex so other threads can make progress.
4. You wait.

But what if the thing you're waiting for happens after you unlocked the mutex but before you waited? You'll be waiting for something that already happened.

This is why the `wait` function takes a lock holder -- so that it can perform steps 3 and 4 atomically.